# MySql, count one column so far and put result in another column

Tags: mysql

3 columns in a table: id (primary key, auto increase), item (varchar), idx (int). Select the table order by id, want to give a sequence index for each item to show its sequence number of the same value, and put the index in idx column. The result is like this:

```
+--+----+---+
|id|item|idx|
+--+----+---+
|1 |a   |1  | < the 1st a
+--+----+---+
|2 |b   |1  | < the 1st b
+--+----+---+
|3 |b   |2  | < the 2nd b
+--+----+---+
|4 |b   |3  | < the 3rd b
+--+----+---+
|5 |a   |2  | < the 2nd a
+--+----+---+
```

How to output this with a select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A correlated subquery getting the count of the rows with the same item and an equal or lower ID should work, also in versions below 8.

```
SELECT t1.id,
       t1.item,
       (SELECT count(*)
               FROM elbat t2
               WHERE t2.item = t1.item
                     AND t2.id <= t1.id) idx
       FROM elbat t1;
```

It might need some tweak though, if `item` is nullable, depending on how you define equality for `NULL` `item`s.

Comment: Salman A's answer is also correct. Thank you both. Sticky bit was earlier so was chosen.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mysql 8 you can use a window function to do this.

```
SELECT id, 
    itm, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY itm ORDER BY id) as idx 
FROM yourtable;
```

Comment: Thank you JNevill for such a quick answer. There is any solution for MySQL 5.7?